# Error in Julia while installing DifferentialEquations package

Tags: julia

I am starting with Julia and trying to install the packages. I am using version 1.5.0 and have Windows 10.  However I am stacked on the following error:

```
  Resolving package versions...
    Cloning [bea87d4a-7f5b-5778-9afe-8cc45184846c] SuiteSparse_jll from https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/SuiteSparse_jll.jl.git
  Installed SuiteSparse_jll ─ v5.4.0+9
Downloading artifact: SuiteSparse
Downloading artifact: SuiteSparse
ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'SuiteSparse' from 'C:\Users\username\.julia\packages\SuiteSparse_jll\CZHvV\Artifacts.toml'
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] ensure_artifact_installed(::String, ::Dict{String,Any}, ::String; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Artifacts.jl:898
 [3] ensure_all_artifacts_installed(::String; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, pkg_uuid::Nothing, include_lazy::Bool, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Artifacts.jl:962
 [4] download_artifacts(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{String,1}; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, verbose::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:656
 [5] download_artifacts(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, verbose::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:635
 [6] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1134
 [7] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:189
 [8] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:140
 [9] #add#21 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [10] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [11] #add#20 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [12] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [13] add(::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:65
 [14] add(::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:65
 [15] top-level scope at REPL[11]:1
 [16] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1088
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried updating packages? Type `]` then `update`

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is choking on installing some Artifacts for a dependency.  This is probably the `Artifacts.toml` it is looking at:

https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/SuiteSparse_jll.jl/blob/main/Artifacts.toml

You can navigate into your `C:/Users/<username>/.julia/packages/SuiteSparse_jll/` directory and see the exact one it is using.

And it is going into the last few lines of that file trying to get it to work on Windows 10 by downloading and unzipping that `.tar.gz` file at the end.

That file has in its bin folder the following dlls:

[image]

So it may be that the package isn't quite working for Julia 1.5 yet... you could try it on a previous version, like Julia 1.3.1.

It may be that you have restricted permissions on downloading or the unzipping failed, though I'd expect a different error.  Or if you have a firewall that is blocking access to that file for some reason.

https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/SuiteSparse_jll.jl/releases/download/SuiteSparse-v5.4.1+3/SuiteSparse.v5.4.1.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz

It should unzip somewhere in `C:/Users/<username>/.julia/artifacts/`